# Unexpected outcome of a="$@"

Tags: bash, string, array, assignment, shellcheck

I'm struggling with this situation:

```
$ set -- 1 2 3
$ a="$@"
$ echo "$a"
1 2 3
```

What I find unexpected is the assignment itself.

`man bash` says this about the `"$@"` expansion:

> When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands
>   to a separate word.

So this should be analogous to:

```
b="1" "2" "3"
bash: 2: command not found
```

And that's what the `"$*"` expansion is for, I gather:

> When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single
>   word with the value of each  parameter  separated by the first
>   character of the IFS special variable. That is, "$*" is equivalent to
>   "$1c$2c...", where c is the first character of the value of the IFS
>   variable. If IFS is unset, the parameters are separated by spaces. If
>   IFS is null, the parameters are  joined without intervening
>   separators.

And so this should be correct:

```
$ set -- 1 2 3
$ a="$*"
$ echo "$a"
1 2 3
```

So why does `"$@"` yield the same? They're supposed to differ in this point. Is this a Bash problem or my misunderstanding?

[Shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) detects this as [SC2124](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2124). I can also provide an example that triggers [SC2145](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2145).

It's observed on:

```
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 (2018-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can tell, [POSIX leaves `$@` in an assignment undefined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02), so it's not really a bug, except maybe in Bash's documentation. `$@` is defined in two cases:

> - When the expansion occurs in a context where field splitting will be performed...
> - When the expansion occurs within double-quotes, the behavior is unspecified unless [...]
>     Field splitting would be performed [...] <sup>(*)</sup>

But,

> In all other contexts the results of the expansion are *unspecified*.

Field splitting doesn't happen in an assignment, and wouldn't happen even without the double quotes, so that's undefined.

---

Now, I assume that `a="$@"` acts about in the same way as `a="$*"` because expanding to multiple words wouldn't really make any sense here. You can't assign multiple words to a regular variable as distinct entities, and assigning one but using the rest as command arguments would be confusing and prone to bugs.

As that shellcheck page says, the behaviour of `"$@"` in an assignment differs between shells. Bash and ksh join the positional parameters with spaces, zsh and dash with the first letter of `IFS` (exactly like `"$*"` would do).

```
$ bash -c 'set -- x y z; IFS=.; a="$@"; printf "<%s>\n" "$a"'
<x y z>
$ ksh93 -c 'set -- x y z; IFS=.; a="$@"; printf "<%s>\n" "$a"'
<x y z>
$ zsh -c 'set -- x y z; IFS=.; a="$@"; printf "<%s>\n" "$a"'
<x.y.z>
$ dash -c 'set -- x y z; IFS=.; a="$@"; printf "<%s>\n" "$a"'
<x.y.z>
```

It's probably best to use `a="$*"` if you want to join to a single string, or otherwise explicitly write what you want.

<sub>(* or another case involving `${parameter:-word}` expansions)</sub>